# How to properly implement leaflet search in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic3

I am trying to search location in the leaflet map. I am using [leaflet-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-search) plugin to achieve this. I tried the following code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-routing-machine';
import 'leaflet-search'


declare var L: any;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map-modal',
  templateUrl: 'map-modal.html',
})
export class MapModalPage {
  map: L.Map;
  center: L.PointTuple;
  searchControl: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  leafletMap() {
    this.map = L.map('mapId', {
      center: this.center,
      zoom: 16
    });

    let searchLayer = L.layerGroup().addTo(this.map);
    this.map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({layer: searchLayer}));


    L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
        attributionControl: false,
        maxNativeZoom: 17,
        maxZoom: 17
      }
    ).addTo(this.map);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.center = [23.762912, 90.430693];
    this.leafletMap();
  }

}
```

The search icon css is not loaded properly.

[image]

Then, when i tried to search for a location, location not found shows.

[image]

What's the perfect way to include leaflet-search. I want below features:

1. How to show suggestion when typing for a location?
2. How to give preference to show the locations of Bangladesh when typing for location?

Comment: I am having trouble using this plugin. Can you tell how you solved the problem?